# Flatten objects in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hey folks I am getting an array of objects from a response. I need to flatten all of the students objects to simply studentName but not certain how. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Example Array:**

```
[
 {
  students: {id: '123456', name: 'Student Name'},
  active: true
 },
 {
  students: {id: '123456', name: 'Student Name'},
  active: true
 }
]
```

**What I am trying to do:**

```
[
 {
  studentName: 'Student Name',
  active: true
 },
 {
  studentName: 'Student Name',
  active: true
 }
]
```

Comment: [{
  students: {id: '123456', name: 'Student Name'},
  active: true
 },
 {
  students: {id: '123456', name: 'Student Name'},
  active: true
 }].map(e => ({studentName: e.students.name, active: e.active}))

Comment: Familiarize yourself with [how to access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON](/q/11922383/4642212) and how to [create objects](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) and use the available static and instance methods of [`Object`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Static_methods) and [`Array`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Static_methods).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create and return a new array of result using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) as:

```js
const arr = [
  {
    students: { id: "123456", name: "Student Name" },
    active: true,
  },
  {
    students: { id: "123456", name: "Student Name" },
    active: true,
  },
];

const result = arr.map(({ students, ...rest }) => ({
  ...rest,
  studentName: students.name,
}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[
  { students: {id: '123456', name: 'Student Name'}, active: true }, 
  { students: {id: '123456', name: 'Student Name'}, active: true }
].map(e => ({studentName: e.students.name, active: e.active}))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the array and set each item's `students` property to the `name` property of the `students` property:

```js
const arr = [
 {students: {id: '123456', name: 'Student Name'},active: true},
 {students: {id: '123456', name: 'Student Name'},active: true}
]


arr.forEach(e => e.students = e.students.name)

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: It should be `studentName`. `forEach` won't work here.

Answer (score 0):

[`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the data and return a new object on each iteration.

```js
const data=[{students:{id:"123456",name:"Student Name"},active:!0},{students:{id:"123456",name:"Student Name"},active:!0}];

const out = data.map(obj => {

  // Destructure the name and active properties
  // from the object
  const { students: { name }, active } = obj;
  
  // Return the new object
  return { studentName: name, active };
});

console.log(out);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.map()` method to rebuild the objects in the array with whatever structure you need.

```js
const arr = [
 {
  students: {id: '123456', name: 'Student Name'},
  active: true
 },
 {
  students: {id: '123456', name: 'Student Name'},
  active: true
 }
];


function flatten(array) {
  return arr.map(({ students, active }) => {
    return {
      studentName: students.name,
      active,
    };
  });
}

console.log(flatten(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
let student =[
 {
  students: {id: '123456', name: 'Student Name'},
  active: true
 },
 {
  students: {id: '123456', name: 'Student Name'},
  active: true
 }
 ];
 
 console.log(student.map(x=> ({ studentName: x.students.name,active: x.active })));
```